# Can't send and receive SMS with LineageOS 14.1

Tags: java, android, sms, android-logcat

I have got a problem with sending and receiving SMS from my mobile (Samsung Galaxy S3) which runs LineageOS 14.1-20170405-NIGHTLY-i9300.
Since a few weeks I can't either send or receive messages with the normal android messaging application and also with SMS applications from the Google Play Store.
I really don't know what to do and it seems like nobody else has got this problem...
The logcat says the following after I tried to send a message:

```
04-08 13:58:50.229 24428-24428/com.android.messaging I/MessagingApp: UI initiated message sending in conversation 3
04-08 13:58:50.365 24428-24635/com.android.messaging I/MessagingAppDataModel: InsertNewMessageAction: inserting new message
04-08 13:58:50.525 24428-24635/com.android.messaging E/MessagingApp: Uncaught exception in background thread Thread[IntentService[ActionService],5,main]
04-08 13:58:50.526 24428-24635/com.android.messaging E/MessagingApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1690)
                                                                         at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                         at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1279)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.sms.i.ahJ(SourceFile:879)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.sms.i.ahz(SourceFile:888)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.InsertNewMessageAction.KA(SourceFile:378)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.InsertNewMessageAction.IV(SourceFile:171)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.ActionServiceImpl.Ji(SourceFile:305)
                                                                         at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.ActionServiceImpl.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:267)
                                                                         at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-08 13:58:50.545 24428-24428/com.android.messaging E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[ActionService]
                                                                       Process: com.android.messaging, PID: 24428
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1690)
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1279)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.sms.i.ahJ(SourceFile:879)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.sms.i.ahz(SourceFile:888)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.InsertNewMessageAction.KA(SourceFile:378)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.InsertNewMessageAction.IV(SourceFile:171)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.ActionServiceImpl.Ji(SourceFile:305)
                                                                           at com.android.messaging.datamodel.action.ActionServiceImpl.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:267)
                                                                           at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Does anybody know what I have to do now?
I really have no idea...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should report this to the creator of your custom ROM instead of asking on this forum.

Comment: Ok...I'll do this in the next days! Thank you for your answer!